# How to flag files/folder as not in solution with DotNetCore projects?

Tags: c#, .net

I've just taken an old project and this project has an MSTest project within the project and weirdly the main solution tries to compile the tests solution within the project.

```
MainSolution -\ 
              \ Tests
```

In my file explorer, I can see the test project folder as if it was a hidden file.

[image: demo]

**How do you avoid that the project makes a reference to the test project**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="Tests\**\*.cs" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

to your `csproj` for the main project.

Long term, I would suggest moving those files.